# Disable bash-completion mode in `shell-command`

Tags: completion

How can I disable the bash-completion like mode in the `shell-command` mini-buffer?

E.g. with `M-!` and then `git diff > <tab>`, emacs shows a list of branches while I expect filename expansion.  Ditto after `git pull /<tab>`; I do not want to expand git remotes there but filenames.

Seen with 'emacs -Q' (29.1)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when I run the commands `git diff > <tab>`, I *do* get the filenames in the completion buffer.
[image: Picture of the filename in the completion buffer when I run the command.]

The completion system for `M-x shell-command` uses `pcomplete` by default. The completion backend is explicitly stored in the function `pcomplete/git`. If you want to disable completion for git, then you can redefine the function `pcomplete/git` to return nil, ex.

```
(defun pcomplete/git ()
  nil)
```